# Cannot pass data from signup form to installation profile

Tags: aegir

I have recently installed `Aegir (6.x-2.1)` on a `Debian 6.0.10` (squeeze) following the instructions found here http://community.aegirproject.org/node/400.

I have followed the instructions found here: https://groups.drupal.org/node/97039, to pass data from signup form to platform's installation profile, but with no luck.

in more details I created a drush script `hosting_school.drush.inc` in my `hosting_school` module and inside the script i have implemented hook `pre_hosting_task`, `drush_hosting_school_pre_hosting_task` . Then I created `drush` script `school_name.drush.inc` in .drush folder and I have implemented hook `pre_provision_install, drush_school_name_pre_provision_install.`

The problem is that while method `drush_hosting_school_pre_hosting_task` is properly invoked, method `drush_school_name_pre_provision_install` is not.

Am i missing something from the instructions ?